# WPF combobox inside listview

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a wpf mvvm application up and running. In one of my views I've got a listbox where one column is a combobox. I thought that I had everything working, but... I ended up here.

When I select a value in the combobox in one row, all rows are changed. I've tried a lot of things and i'm stuck.

Here's my xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Properties.OutputGroups, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView >
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Output" >
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.Outputs}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Obj.OutputID, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" SelectedValuePath="ID" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Duration">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Obj.Duration}" BorderThickness="0" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="State" >
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Obj.State}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: Please post your model.  My guess is that each combo item points to the same object instance.

Comment: I wish. But it's only the first column with the combobox that changes on all rows. The other columns are fine. I've also debuged and check that the setter is in fact called for all objects. I've also checked that the hash code is different, just to be sure

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive about this, so I apologize if this is not correct, but according to what I have read on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx), I think it might have to do with the "isSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" property.  Try switching this property to "true," and see if that fixes your problem.

Like I said, I'm not positive this is where the problem is, but it seems to me like you are wanting the data to be synchronized with the current item, hence why that property is throwing up a flag to me.

I really hope this helps! (And I truly apologize if it doesn't)

Comment: well, if you read the page on msdn you'll see "The following example binds two ListBox controls to the same ItemsSource. Because IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem is set to true on each ListBox, the selected item is always the same for both controls." If I read this correct it's exactly the same behaviour that I've got now. So setting it to false should be right.

Comment: @Furnes - Sorry about that, it was a shot in the dark, but a shot nonetheless. I'll keep looking to see if I can find anything else.  Sorry again for this not being helpful, though!